# Highcharts numberformat

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
name: 'Name',
data: [1.57,1.57,1.51,1.44,1.44,1.37,1.35,1.33,1.33,1.27,1.27,1.24,1.22,0.98],
    color: '#A61E22',
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        rotation: -90,
        color: '#000000',
        align: 'right',
        x: 4,
        y: -35,
        style: {
            fontSize: '10px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
    }                                       
}]
```

I have the following code. Is there any way to use the function number format throughout the series? I need to replace the dots by commas. I need the number format like this:

```
number_format (series_values, 2, ',', '.');
```

Answer (score 17):

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        decimalPoint: ',',
        thousandsSep: '.'
    },

    tooltip: {
        yDecimals: 2 // If you want to add 2 decimals
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8dmhd/)

*Reference*

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.decimalPoint
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.thousandsSep
- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.yDecimals

Comment: Hi , i'm very new to this. I wanted to know if there is language support for highcharts. It would be great if you can just help me out.Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

Not sure yDecimals is working now. Seem to be tooltip.valueDecimals now.

Here what I'm using :

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        decimalPoint: ',',
        thousandsSep: '.'
    }
});
```

And in the chart :

```
tooltip: {
    valueDecimals: 2 
},
```

Comment: Indeed yDecimals did not work for me today, while valueDecimals did. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use formatter for tooltip / labels

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter

and then use numberFormat:
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.numberFormat